# How to create queue in wso2 ESB remotly

Tags: web-services, wso2-esb

I want to call a web-service on wso2 ESB  and this web-service create a new queue and endpoint if already not exist name queue. For example:

```
http://192.168.0.1:8080/createqueue?name=q1&endpoint='20.0.0.1/adduser'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Through ESB, you can create proxies, message stores, sequences and APIs as required. Please refer [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/WSO2+Enterprise+Service+Bus+Documentation) regarding ESB functionalities